# How can I make Notepad++ appear when I type "notepad"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, notepad++, start-menu, notepad

I installed Notepad++ on Windows 10 and set it as the default `.txt` file editor.  However, when I open the start menu and type "notepad" I still get regular Notepad as the top result; Notepad++ is a small second result.  How do I make it give me Notepad++ as the top result?

Answer (score 4):

Use notepad++ more often. Windows 10 sorts it by multiple factors including how many times you’ve used notepad++ more than notepad.

Comment: My Windows 10 installation does this. No trickery or other programs, after a while it learned my preference.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to go to the shortcut and mark it as hidden. You won't be modifying/deleting any shortcuts, just stopping windows from showing it in the start menu and search.

Search for "Notepad", right click -> "Open File Location", then right click on the file -> "Properties" -> General -> and check the box marked "Hidden"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the "notepad" that pops up is just a shortcut to the original notepad. if you don't require this anymore, just type notepad in the 'search' field, rightclick on the 1st notepad that pops up and change the target locations and the start in locations to mirror those found in the notepad++ shortcut. If you want to reverse the changes, just ensure you make a note of the original locations.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's not a 100% clear if it's supposed to be limited to search results from the start menu (I think those go by frequency of use) or generally want to get Notepad++ when you try to execute something via the `notepad`. I'll answer for the generic case.

---

For some time now Windows has allowed to set this, but I think it only technically works for `ShellExecute()` and friends, not for `CreateProcess()`. Roughly meaning this may not work in `cmd.exe` or other software using the latter, but it will work in the "Run" dialog box (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and other software using the former.

The way it works is:

- system-wide: at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`
- user-local: at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`

Underneath that key create a key named after an `.exe` you want to execute. E.g. `notepad.exe`. Then set the default value of the newly created key to the full path of the `.exe` to execute in its place. E.g. `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`.

As a side-note: these days Notepad++ appears to already do exactly that for the system-wide option.

### system-wide as `.reg` file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
```

### user-local as `.reg` file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\notepad.exe]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
```

NB: please don't confuse this with the App Execution Aliases. It's not the same feature, but one that has a functional overlap.